# hacked contract

Tags: solidity, web3js, contract-development, remix

Unfortunately, the contract we created with great hopes last night was hacklendi. we still do not understand how it is, the owner's address is changed. we are trying to figure this out because we want to fix it in our next contract. Please click to go to the [contract](https://etherscan.io/address/0x102e3bcc2fb6a2fe4c1c4cf09021a5638008b721#code).

Is there anyone who can help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a function that anyone can call to make themselves `owner`:

```
function HTX () public {
    owner = msg.sender;
    uint256 devTokens = 1000000000e8;
    distr(owner, devTokens);
}
```

This was probably meant to be a constructor. In current versions of Solidity, this should be:

```
constructor() public {
     ...
```

but it's also still acceptable (but deprecated) to use a function with the same name as the contract. In this case:

```
function HitexToken() public {
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your reply. well, Is there a way to get this contract back?

Comment: Well, you can call `HTX()` and become the `owner` again, but I don't see the point. There are no more tokens and no more ether. (And anyone can come along at any time to become `owner` again.)

Comment: I am trying to change the owner address but "ALERT: Transaction Error. Exception thrown in contract code." I get an error. https://ibb.co/dgpoiU

Comment: Is the account you're using currently the `owner`? You can't call `transferOwnership` unless you're the `owner`.

Comment: no. This is the old account holder. this creator address. then hacked and changed. I am trying to make the address again as the owner of this contract. am applying the wrong method?

Comment: As I said, you can call `HTX()` to do that. (So can anyone else.)